# "You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders" while installing ACS SDK 1.22.2

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sdk, babel-loader, acs

I am trying to update Microsoft ACS SDK to the latest version (1.22.2), after updating my package.json and then running "yarn install", the latest SDK successfully gets installed but now when I try to build and run the project by running "yarn start", the build fails and throws this error:

```bash
./node_modules/@azure/communication-calling/dist/sdk.bundle.js 14197:112
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (14197:112)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|             return g.stack && (g.stack = processStackTrace(g.stack)), (m ? JSON.stringify(g) : JSON.stringify(g, Ne, 4)).replace(/(\r\n\t|\n|\r\t|\s)/gm, "");
|           } catch (m) {
>             return `failed to get error information:${g && "function" == typeof g.toString && g.toString()} ${g?.response && JSON.stringify(g.response)}`;
|           }
|         }
```

I cleared the yarn cache, removed the node_modules folder and did a fresh install (yarn install), but nothing seems to be working.